# Block.io token withdrawal

Tags: api, cryptoapi

With Block.IO token withdrawal it seems we need to send more signature as per their doc: https://block.io/api/simple/signing

Like to know how to send cURL to execute (with more signature) ?

Their sample cURL is not working: 
/api/v2/withdraw_from_addresses/?api_key=API KEY&from_addresses=ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,...&to_addresses=ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,...&amounts=AMOUNT1,AMOUNT2,...

response for above cURL is:

```
{[status, success]}
{[data, {
  "reference_id": "24fe5a.....",
  "more_signatures_needed": true,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "input_no": 0,
      "signatures_needed": 1,
      "data_to_sign": "2498d....",
      "signers": [
        {
          "signer_address": "1H4.....",
          "signer_public_key": "037710.....",
          "signed_data": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "encrypted_passphrase": {
    "signer_address": "1H4...",
    "signer_public_key": "0377....",
    "passphrase": "fDCM0...."
  },
  "unsigned_tx_hex": "01000...."
}]}
```

For your kind info. I am using PAID version but their support team not replied yet for this query. Friends, if anyone knows please support me to find a solution for token-withdrawal using API

preferred language is ASP.Net VB  (if possible explain with sample codes pls. for better understanding)

Comment: Have you implemented the "Steps to a Successful Client-Side Signature" from the doc you linked?

Comment: No, i didn't. can you explain where and how to implement. whether its one time implementation or for every request i need to implement client-side signature...?

Comment: I don't know the API but I'd guess yes, you'll need to generate a new signature for every request you make e.g. so that the signature covers the exact amounts and addresses you're withdrawing from. It might be simplest to switch to using one of the languages that they provide a library for.

Comment: Rup, thanks for your comment. Let me try